# Code stops and reports no exceptions (using "requests")

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python. I tried to recreate the "Timer" control used in .NET Framework ("Timer" in Python is a different thing...). So, basically, I created a function named **CheckMessages** that, after its execution, stops the main thread for 1 second and then calls again **CheckMessages**. Under *normal* circumstances (=when no exception in the code is thrown), this works good. The *timing* between one execution and the next is obviously not precise (it is *never* 1 second) but for the scope of my app this is not a problem. 
The problem is: when an exception is thrown, nothing happens. The code does not follow my *try ... except* logic (no logs are shown) and the app does not exit.

```py
import time
import sched
import requests

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

def CheckMessages(sc):
    newMsgsReq = ""
    try:

        newMsgsReq = requests.get("...")

    except requests.HTTPError as errh:
        print ("Http Error:",errh)
    except requests.ConnectionError as errc:
        print ("Connection Error:",errc)
    except requests.Timeout as errt:
        print ("Timeout Error:",errt)
    except requests.RequestException as err:
        print ("OOps: Something Else",err)

    msgInf = newMsgsReq.text.split("|")

    #...

    s.enter(1, 1, CheckMessages, (sc,))

s.enter(1, 1, CheckMessages, (s,))
s.run()
```

When, for example, I disable my internet connection, I would expect my app to report: *Connection Error:...* (line 11 of the code snippet). Instead, as said, nothing happens. The app remains active but the output is empty. The function **CheckMessages** stops being executed every 1 sec.

Comment: Try excepting a generic ```Exception``` and see what happens

Comment: You may want to add some print statements for debugging.  Are you sure CheckMessages is initiating?

Comment: @MichaelBianconi same exact problem...

Comment: @James yes it is, because of `s.enter(1, 1, CheckMessages, (s,))`. Also, when no exception is thrown, the code works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When I put in an invalid URL ("http://sdkls9e9i.ooo"), I see the exception printed successfully.

After an exception from requests is handled, the script quits with `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'` because you attempt to work with the response (`msgInf = newMsgsReq.text.split("|")`) after you've handled an exception.

When I followed your lead and disabled my internet connection, the script indeed "hang". Hitting CTRL+C revealed that it was waiting in:

```
File ".../site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
  sock.connect(sa)
```

After I added a [timeout](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts): `requests.get("...", timeout=1)`, I got the exception as well.

P.S. note that PEP 8 style guide recommends using [`lower_case_with_underscore` for variable and function names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names).